# I want to know my chance of getting a visa to Norway to visit my wife

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-refusals, norway

this is the third time I'm considering applying for a visa to Norway and I have been rejected twice. Firstly, I was rejected because the consider my relationship with my girlfriend that I was to visit as not an esblished relationship since we haven't met in person and we only met online, then my girlfriend visited me we got married she returned then I applied to visit her because she is undergoing surgery in September and she want me to be with her but I got rejected on the following Grounds:

> Justification for the purpose of intended stay has not been    provided. Reference is made to the fact that the applicant's and the reference's marriage has not been registered in the Norwegian population system.
>
> The applicant wishes to visit his wife. However, the embassy does not consider this a satisfactory reason that outweighs the applicant's necessary tie with his home country.
>
> We have noted that the applicant comes from a country with a great potential for emigration due to its social and economic situation. In our experience, many applicants fail from west Africa wish to resettle in other countries.
>
> The applicant is relatively young, married and has no children. He has not stated to have property or other financial commitments in his home country.
>
> After considering these aspect of the application, the embassy finds that the applicant lack the necessary ties with his country of origin.

These were the reasons that they gave, she is suggesting to get the marriage registered in their population system and to reapply since she is expecting to undergo a surgery on the 5th of September and want me to be with her as she does not have anyone to take care of
Can someone help me with solutions that will increase my chance of getting the visa so that I can be with her through her surgery.

Comment: It's a duplicate at the moment, if you want to clarify your wife's nationality and status in Norway it can possibly be migrated to Expats for a other routes available to you.